# Change Default billing address for Guest

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-api

We are trying to change the default billing address for a guest user with the Store-API. But the function call `setDefaultCustomerBillingAddress` is allowed only for register customer, does someone have a smart solution for this?

We try this operation with the `setDefaultCustomerBillingAddress`.
But it returns:

Error:

```json
{
  "messages": [
    {
      "status": "403",
      "code": "CHECKOUT__CUSTOMER_NOT_LOGGED_IN",
      "title": "Forbidden",
      "detail": "Customer is not logged in.",
      "meta": {
        "parameters": []
      }
    }
  ],
  "statusCode": 403
}
```

Comment: This question can be a little confusing since I'm assuming you're referring to a function of Shopware Frontends, formerly known as PWA, specifically [this one](https://frontends.shopware.com/packages/api-client/setDefaultCustomerBillingAddress.html), right?

The error on the server-side is pretty clear. The endpoint updates the address of the currently logged-in customer, but there is no currently logged-in customer. Are you explicitly passing the `contextInstance` argument?

Comment: Hi, 
no, the problem is that we can to try this operation for the guest user, that for definition is not logged in. 
But in the meantime  we solved the problem by developing a custom plugin that exposes me a specific endpoint.